# How to change the order of bars in a matplotlib barchart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime


co2_prices = [100, 60]
electricity_prices = [-2.6, 157]
co2_timestamps = ["March 2023", "February 2024"]
electricity_timestamps = ["24.09.2023 14:00", "24.09.2023 19:00"]


co2_timestamps = [datetime.strptime(date, "%B %Y") for date in co2_timestamps]
electricity_timestamps = [datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M") for date in electricity_timestamps]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()


bar_width = 0.35

co2_positions = range(len(co2_prices))
electricity_positions = [pos + bar_width for pos in co2_positions]

# Plot bars for CO2 prices
ax.bar(co2_positions, co2_prices, bar_width, label='CO2 Prices (€/T)')

ax.bar(electricity_positions, electricity_prices, bar_width, label='Electricity Prices (€/MWh)')

all_positions = list(co2_positions) + list(electricity_positions)
all_labels = ["March 2023", "February 2024", "24.09.2023 14:00", "24.09.2023 19:00"]

ax.set_xticks(all_positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(all_labels, rotation=45, ha="right")

ax.set_xlabel('Timeline')
ax.set_ylabel('Prices')
ax.set_title('CO2 and Electricity Prices')


ax.legend()


plt.show()
```

to display a barchart with 4 entries. The entries for the

`co2_prices = [100, 60]`

should be next to each other with the corresponding labels

```
co2_timestamps = ["March 2023", "February 2024"]
```

and the entries for the

`electricity_prices = [-2.6, 157]`

should be next to each other with the corresponding labels

`electricity_timestamps = ["24.09.2023 14:00", "24.09.2023 19:00"]`.

In the current code the bars for the `co2_prices` are not next to each other, and I tried several solution to change it, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the bar position you are putting the each electricity bar just after the co2 bar because you are distancing them only one bar width. Since the position for the co2 are 0 and 1, you should put the electricity in 2 and 3 with:

```
electricity_positions = [pos + 2 for pos in co2_positions]
```

Moreover if you want the bar for the same categories (electricity or co2) touching the bar width should be 1.

Complete working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime


co2_prices = [100, 60]
electricity_prices = [-2.6, 157]
co2_timestamps = ["March 2023", "February 2024"]
electricity_timestamps = ["24.09.2023 14:00", "24.09.2023 19:00"]

co2_timestamps = [datetime.strptime(date, "%B %Y") for date in co2_timestamps]
electricity_timestamps = [datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M") for date in electricity_timestamps]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


bar_width = 0.8
tras = 3

co2_positions = range(len(co2_prices))
electricity_positions = [pos + tras for pos in co2_positions]

# Plot bars for CO2 prices
ax.bar(co2_positions, co2_prices, bar_width, label='CO2 Prices (€/T)')

ax.bar(electricity_positions, electricity_prices, bar_width, label='Electricity Prices (€/MWh)')

all_positions = list(co2_positions) + list(electricity_positions)
all_labels = ["March 2023", "February 2024", "24.09.2023 14:00", "24.09.2023 19:00"]

ax.set_xticks(all_positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(all_labels, rotation=45, ha="right")

ax.set_xlabel('Timeline')
ax.set_ylabel('Prices')
ax.set_title('CO2 and Electricity Prices')

ax.set_ylim([-20, 160]) # y axis limits


ax.legend()

ax.grid(alpha=0.5) # grid, alpha is the opacity of the lines
plt.tight_layout() # tight layout, allow for better visualization in the window

plt.show()
```

The `tras` variable is the translation between the first box of the co2 and the first of the electricity and the same for the respective second box.

I added both the limits for the y axis (starting from -20 so you see also the negative values), the grid which I prefer for readibility and the tight layout because the plot was not fitting in the window properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer bona. Can I adjust the y-axis such that it begins at 0 and thus there is no empty space between the bars and the x-axis? Further the bars for the co2- prices should be closer to each other (lilke a cluster) and also the bars for the electricity price should be closer to each other

Comment: To have closer bar I suggest you increase the bar width (1 will be bars touching) and to have the two group further apart you need only to increase the number you are adding to the co2 position, so 3 or more.

Comment: Regarding the start form 0 you can do it specifying the limit for the y axis with

ax.set_ylim([0, 160])

however I'd suggest to start from a lower number since you have a negative price for the first electricity price

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I dont understand how I can do the grouping on the two bars for co2 and the two bars for electricity price

Comment: I'd add a complete example in the answer

Comment: In any case, the range function you use for the co2 position generates 0 and 1, so to separate the two groups you need to translate (the variable tras, the number you add to the c02 position to get the electricity position) more than 2 units away, so that the first position of the electricity is higher than 1.